# More elegant way of handling this method?

Tags: java

Below is a method used in my application that reassigns a vehicle to a depot. Is there a better way of handling these conditionals than the boolean statements I have in place?

Some things to note are `Vehicle` and `Depot` are classes and `Depot` has an ArrayList of `Vehicles` Inside it. `depoNo` is set earlier in the program in order for the program to know what depot to reference in the `Depots` arraylist. 
`vehicleSelection` is used to get the users choice of vehicle.`depotSelection` is used in the same manner apart from applying to `Depots`

Most of the error checking is handled by the boolean's, but this makes the code look extremely ugly and long winded, what would be the best case scenario for me to do here?

````
    public void reAssignVehicles()
    {
        String vehicleSelection;
        String depotSelection = "";
        boolean exit = false, validReg = false, validLocation = false;
        int i = 0; // used to count which depot selected
        Vehicle v;
        if (!depots.get(depotNo).getVehicles().isEmpty())
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.println("Depots");
                depots.get(depotNo).listVehicles();
                System.out.printf("%nSelect the registration number of the vehicle you wish to reassign: %n");
                vehicleSelection = input.nextLine();
                for (Vehicle vehicle : depots.get(depotNo).getVehicles())
                {

                    if (vehicleSelection.equals(vehicle.getRegNo()))
                    {
                        validReg = true;
                        System.out.printf("%nYou have selected vehicle: %s%n", vehicleSelection);
                        listDepots();
                        System.out.printf("%nPlease select the depot you want to reassign this vehicle to: %n");
                        depotSelection = input.nextLine();

                        for (Depot d : depots)
                        {
                            if (depotSelection.equals(d.getDepotLocation()) && !depotSelection.equals(vehicle.getDepot())) // if the vehicle exists at depot
                            {
                                validLocation = true;
                                System.out.printf("%nVehicle %s is now assigned to %s%n", vehicleSelection, depotSelection);
                                    exit = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            else
                            {
                                validLocation = false;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        validReg = false;
                    }

                }
                if (!validReg) //To prompt user to enter correct information
                {
                    System.out.printf("Please select a valid registration%n%n");
                }
                if (!validLocation)
                {
                    System.out.printf("%nThe vehicle is either already assigned to the depot, or the depot does not exist%n%n");
                }
                if (validLocation) {
                    v = depots.get(depotNo).getVehiclebyReg(vehicleSelection);
                    v.setDepot(getDepot(depotSelection));
                    depots.get(i).makeVehicle(v);
                    depots.get(depotNo).getVehicles().remove(v);
                }

            } while (!exit);
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no vehicles in the Depot to reassign");
        }
```
````

Comment: I do *not* want to guess what `depots` or `input` is: Please provide enough context to support meaningful reviews. Heed [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is quite a bit of context missing for a good review, most importantly: What is the purpose of the class that this method belongs to? This method contains a mixture of frontend code and buiness code, suggesting that you generally haven't divided up your code properly.

Also why does this class have a field `depotNo`, which only serves as the argument in the expression `depots.get(depotNo)` multiple times? At the very least this method should call `Depot depot = depots.get(depotNo);` once. Better would be that `Depot depot` be either a field in the class (replacing `depotNo`) or be an argument passed to this method.

---

Don't define all your variables at the start of the method. Allways define them as late as possible in the smallest needed scope.

---

Keep the number of indention levels as low as possible. For example, at the start instead of putting the whole functionallity inside the `if (!depots.get(depotNo).getVehicles().isEmpty())` block, exit the method there and then and put the rest of the code on the same level:

```
public void reAssignVehicles() {
  Depot depot = depots.get(depotNo);
  if (depot.getVehicles().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("There are no vehicles in the Depot to reassign");
      return;
  }

  do {
     // ...
```

---

You also loop over the list of vehicles to find the selected vehicle, however have and use a method that already does that, so you are looking up the vehicle twice.

---

Comment: The reason I only added this method is because much of the code is similar to this, with what you've suggested I have plenty to fix, including using depots.get throughout my code. So thank you for that you've said I have plenty to fix now!

Comment: Since it is definitely missing context this question should not have been answered, there should have been a comment and a vote to close.

Comment: @David Next time, please don't forget to post the rest of the context as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!depots.get(depotNo).getVehicles().isEmpty())
{
    ... lots of code
} else {
    System.out.println("There are no vehicles in the Depot to reassign");
}
```

Here the `println` is performed and then the method returns. In that case it is better to perform a **positive** if and then exit early:

```
if (depots.get(depotNo).getVehicles().isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("There are no vehicles in the Depot to reassign");
    return;
}
```

... lots of code

That does the same thing, but it means you don't have to indent the code. It immediately makes clear what the program does if the depot is empty, and then lets the reader forget about it.

Note that you either use Egyptian brackets (braces) or you don't. Most Java programmers do use it, so I would place the brace at the end of the `if` statement. However, if you don't then:

```
} else {
```

is not consequent, you would use:

```
}
else
{
```

instead.

---

```
 do
```

Generally there is no need to document a `do ... while` loop, but if the `while` is that far away, you need to make clear what the loop does here.

---

```
String depotSelection = "";
```

This is not very Java-like. In Java you declare the variable as late as possible. And if you assign it a value anyway, then you don't first need to assign the empty string to it.

---

```
int i = 0; // used to count which depot selected
```

Why not call it `selectedDepotNr` in that case? Then you don't need the comment anymore. Besides, a *count* is not an identifier.

And it defaults to zero? Why? Is zero some kind of magic value?

---

```
System.out.println("Depots");
```

You are mixing the user interface code with the "business logic", which is not a good idea. If you create a method then you need to separate the retrieval of user input and the actual running of the code. That of course also goes for `input.nextLine`.

---

```
depots.get(depotNo).listVehicles();
```

There there is a depot that performs output. First of all, it is entirely unclear that `listVehicles` produces output at all (`printVehicles` is better), but nowadays we try and not let the data object perform the output itself, let alone let it choose where to output it.

---

```
depots.get(depotNo).listVehicles();
System.out.printf("%nSelect the registration number of the vehicle you wish to reassign: %n");
vehicleSelection = input.nextLine();
for (Vehicle vehicle : depots.get(depotNo).getVehicles())
```

Here `depots.get(depotNo)` gets called twice in quick succession, with the same `depotNo`. In that case you should assign to a `depot` variable so the method is only called *once*. Lookup the DRY principle.

---

```
!depotSelection.equals(vehicle.getDepot())
```

So the source must not equal the destination, but that's kind of added to an afterthought. And it seems to break if `getDepot()` return a `Depot` type instead of a `String`. If it returns a `String` representing a location then certainly the method is not named correctly. So it is wrong either way.

---

```
i++;
```

Oh, dear, that doesn't happen at the right place at all. First of all, how do you determine if `i` remains valid? Doesn't it overflow, because it is 2 loops deep? If the `do ... while` gets executed twice then you're in trouble, right?

---

```
System.out.printf("%nThe vehicle is either already assigned to the depot, or the depot does not exist%n%n");
```

Ah, right, so how would you feel as a user if you got this message? Now you will have to find out which one of the two errors is happening?

---

```
if (validLocation) {
```

Wait, I'm pretty sure that I just saw an `if (!validLocation)`! what about `else`?

---

```
} while (!exit);
```

I don't know but I presume that we could use `break LABEL` if that's necessary. Removes an unnecessary boolean, for instance.

---

```
depots.get(i).makeVehicle(v);
```

I've never seen a depot make a vehicle. If the code doesn't seem to fit reality then the code is wrong. It really is that simple. You are reassigning, why not `assignVehicle`?

---

What you've programmed is unfortunately what we call spaghetti-code. All kinds of loops and branches (`if` and such) and mixing of methods, UI code.

The design is not correct either. `vehicle.getDepot()` means that a vehicle has got a specific depot assigned to it. Is that a changing depot? In that case it is not part of the vehicle object. Maybe there is a *map* somewhere with a vehicle -> depot mapping, but making a depot part of a vehicle is not a good design.

Besides that, the depots already list which vehicles are present. Having two related references stored at different locations is just asking for the program to get into an invalid state. If that's present then the update needs to be performed *within a single, indivisible method*, i.e. more or less at the same time.

I would expect at least the following methods to implement the UI logic (in a separate UI class):

- `Depot selectOriginatingDepot()`;
- `void listVehiclesByRegistration(Depot depot)`;
- `Vehicle selectVehicleByRegistration()`;
- `Depot selectTargetDepot(Depot originatingDepot)`.

Furthermore, I would expect the following methods for the business logic (so no printing or scanner usage, use a logger if you have to):

- `Optional<Depot> getDepotByLocation(String location)`;

This is already there, but it requires some rewriting using `Optional`.

- `Optional<Vehicle> Depot#getVehicleByRegistration(String registration)`;

Now if the `Optional` is "empty" then you can simply let UI code ask again.

---

By using more methods you will have fewer boolean to worry about for each specific method. Furthermore, by using smarter constructs such as `Optional` and e.g. `HashTable` you might find that you can program this entire piece of code without using a single booleanor nested loops for that matter.